# External List filtering using Web Part Connections (send filter value to)

Tags: filter, bdc-model, web-part-connection

I have an external list (WCF) and I would like to have another web part that searches 1 or more columns on the list (e.g. Product Title, and Product Status etc)

I'm using SP2013, guess it would be the same for SP2010

The out-of-box filtering wouldn't work because I have paging on my list, and I only fetch 1 page at a time (because I have thousands of items). so the out-of-box filter will only search on match items in that 1 page.

My current list is deployed from a Sharepoint project, it is a Business Data Connectivity Model(farm solution only).

Here's part of my BDCM and controller:

```
  <LobSystems>
    <LobSystem Name="PortalExtListBdcModel" Type="DotNetAssembly">
      <LobSystemInstances>
        <LobSystemInstance Name="PortalExtListBdcModel"/>
      </LobSystemInstances>
      <Entities>

        <Entity EstimatedInstanceCount="1000" Name="ProductEdgeEntity" Namespace="SPPortal.PortalExtListBdcModel" Version="1.0.0.0">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="Class" Type="System.String">SPPortal.PortalExtListBdcModel.Controllers, PortalExtListBdcModel</Property>
          </Properties>
          <Identifiers>
            <Identifier TypeName="System.String" Name="IM_STOCK" />
          </Identifiers>
          <Methods>
            <Method Name="ProductEdgeReadList">
              <FilterDescriptors>
                <FilterDescriptor Type="UserContext" Name="UserContextFilter">
                  <Properties>
                    <Property Name="UsedForDisambiguation" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
                    <Property Name="IsDefault" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
                    <Property Name="CaseSensitive" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
                  </Properties>
                </FilterDescriptor>
              </FilterDescriptors>
              <Parameters>
                <Parameter Direction="In" Name="UCFilter">
                  <TypeDescriptor Significant="true" TypeName="System.String"  Name="UCFilter" AssociatedFilter="UserContextFilter">
                    <DefaultValues>
                      <DefaultValue MethodInstanceName="ProductEdgeReadList" Type="System.String"></DefaultValue>
                    </DefaultValues>
                  </TypeDescriptor>
                </Parameter>
                <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="returnParameter">
                  <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[SPPortal.PortalExtListBdcModel.PrismProductListView, PortalExtListBdcModel]]" IsCollection="true" Name="ProductEdgeEntityList">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor TypeName="SPPortal.PortalExtListBdcModel.PrismProductListView, PortalExtListBdcModel" Name="ProductEdgeEntity">
                        <TypeDescriptors>
                          <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.String" IdentifierName="IM_STOCK" Name="IM_STOCK" />
                          <TypeDescriptor Name="IM_DESC" TypeName="System.String" DefaultDisplayName="Description" />
                          <TypeDescriptor Name="IM_CUST" TypeName="System.String" DefaultDisplayName="Customer Code" />


        public static IEnumerable<PrismProductListView> ProductEdgeReadList(string UCFilter)
        {
            // get from WCF service and return list
        }
```

I also worked out how to have a Web part send values to another web part using the following:

```
[ConnectionProvider("Title")]
[ConnectionConsumer("Title")]
```

But I'm trouble having the web part send values to my BDCM

Does anyone has examples on how to modify the BDCM (the xml above) to take parameters (direction=IN) from the web part?

Or if there are other ways to achieve this?

Thanks!